# Set custom page title on home in magento

Tags: magento

I am showing only a single product on home page.  I want to show the product name in page title.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple ways of doing this:

1. **In your module's layout xml file (located at app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/{your_file_name}.xml):**

   ```
   <reference name="head">
       <action method="setTitle"><title>Title text here</title></action>
   </reference>
   ```

   The bad thing here is that you can't set tittle "on the fly".
2. **In your block file** (`_prepareLayout()` method is a good place)**:**

   ```
   public function _prepareLayout() 
   {
       $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
       $headBlock->setTitle('Title text here');
       return parent::_prepareLayout();
   }
   ```
3. **Anywhere else:**

   ```
   Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Title text here');
   ```

**Useful link -** [Layouts, Blocks and Templates](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates)